# Clear cell each 10 seconds in worksheet change

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code I am trying to make the cell A1 empty each 10 seconds and at the same time to be able to work on the other cells or even any other worksheet without interrupt.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim t As Date

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    t = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
    Do

        If Now() >= t Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("A1").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Do
            End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End If
End Sub
```

The code may work and clear the cell contents but sometimes I found that it is not cleared and filled with the value entered in another cell. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I might use `Application.OnTime` here.

Comment: Will using onTime affect the use of the other cells in the worksheet or the use of any worksheet ..?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: Can you please give me example of worksheet change to use it, Just to affect only on cell A1?

Comment: There are examples all over the internet on how to use `Application.OnTime` to run some vba/macro every N seconds.

Comment: I am confused in the worksheet change event `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "How to call worksheet change here"`

Comment: Why are you using `Worksheet_Change`?  Use `OnTime` as suggested, and just call a Sub in a regular module.

Comment: @Tim Williams and what about the effect of the other cells while changing the values of any other cell. I just wanted to affect on A1 cell so I used Worksheet_Change.

Comment: If your sub does nothing with the other cells then they will be unaffected...

Comment: If I use onTime, the code will work forever and every 10 seconds even if I didn't change the value in A1. The purpose is to make the clear event only after 10 seconds of changing A1 only. And then if any cell changed nothing would happen.

Comment: What you wanted was not really clear from the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        'existing call to clear?
        If scheduled > 0 Then Application.OnTime scheduled, "ClearIt", schedule:=False
        scheduled = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
        Application.OnTime scheduled, "ClearIt", schedule:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```
Public scheduled

Sub ClearIt()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    scheduled = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot for your awesome solution.